# jQuery Calculator Convert to Feet / Inches

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I have a BMI Calculator which is working perfectly however my client would now like to offer the user the ability to switch from its current measurements of CMs + KGs to offer Stones, Feet and Inches. I'm not entirely sure how I would go about converting that though.

My code is as follows:

```
$("#height").bind(
    "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
        $("#height_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
        calculateBMI();
    }
    );

$("#weight").bind(
    "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
        $("#weight_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
        calculateBMI();
    }
    );

function calculateBMI(){
    var weight = $("#weight_value").html();
    var height = parseInt($("#height_value").html())/100;
    var bmi = weight / (height * height);

    var type = "Normal";

    var imageResult = $('#image-result');
    var classes = 'underweight overweight obese very-obese normal-weight';

    if (bmi < 15){
        type= "Score below 20: Underweight";
        imageResult.removeClass(classes);
        imageResult.addClass('underweight');
    }else if(bmi <=24.9){
        type= "Score: 20-25: Normal Weight";
        imageResult.removeClass(classes);
        imageResult.addClass('normal-weight');
    }else if(bmi <=29.9){
        type= "Score 26-30:Overweight";
        imageResult.removeClass(classes);
        imageResult.addClass('overweight');
    }else if(bmi <=34.9){
        type= "Score 31-40:Obese";
        imageResult.removeClass(classes);
        imageResult.addClass('obese');
    }else{
        type= "Score: 40+:Very Obese";
        imageResult.removeClass(classes);
        imageResult.addClass('very-obese');
    }
    $("#result").html("<small>"+type+"</small>");
    $('#bmi-index').html(bmi.toFixed(1));
}
calculateBMI();
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Always work in metric (just because the values are easier to work with and store) and just multiply by the necessary factor to convert to other units

Comment: Maybe your client should employ us if you want us to do the work for you?

Comment: This was my first post here. I thought this was a community to get help from, not patronising comments.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I managed to convert it by inserting this:

```
$("#height").bind(
    "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
        $("#height_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
        var inches = (data.value*0.393700787).toFixed(0);
        var feet = Math.floor(inches / 12);
        inches %= 12;
        $("#height_value_in").html(feet + "ft " + inches + 'in');
        calculateBMI();
    }
    );

$("#weight").bind(
    "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
        $("#weight_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
        $("#weight_value_pounds").html((data.value*2.20462).toFixed(0) + 'lb' );
        calculateBMI();
    }
    );
```